# How can I install and test Connect IQ Data Field on my device

Tags: garmin

I was able to use the SDK to build a custom DataField, but don't see any info included with the SDK about how or if I can directly install and test this on my device. I've tested this with the simulator, but would like to try it to see how it works on my GPS device.  Do I need to download a separate tool to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the side load option.  Connect your device to computer move the prj file to the GARMIN/APPS directory.  https://developer.garmin.com/connect-iq/programmers-guide/getting-started/